# Getting a multipart.File into image.Decode as argument

Tags: image, go, multipart

The contents of the multipart.File are as follows: "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD..."

I'm trying to get it into the Image.DecodeConfig() method like this:

```
import (
    "image"
    "image/jpeg"
    "io"
)

func ImgCheckSize(file io.Reader) (io.Reader, error) {
    config, format, err := image.DecodeConfig(file)
...
```

The error prints: "image: unknown format"

I've also printed out the multipart.FileHeader.Header which reads:

```
map[Content-Disposition:[form-data; name="img1"; filename="img1"] Content-Type:[application/octet-stream]]
```

Has anyone come across this before? Any useful suggestions would help! Many many thanks

Comment: The image is encoded as a [data URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs). The image decoder expects the raw image bytes.  Decode the data URL.

Comment: Thanks. I've done this with the following package: "github.com/vincent-petithory/dataurl". So: `imgdecoded, _ := dataurl.Decode(imgupload)`. Or is there an easier way to do this just using the Standard Lib?

Comment: The standard library does not have a data URL parser, but it's not difficult to write one.  I suggest writing an answer with how you solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved with the following package: "github.com/vincent-petithory/dataurl"

for example:

imgdecoded, _ := dataurl.Decode(imgupload)

Answer (score 1):

As it states in the image package’s documentation (https://golang.org/pkg/image/ 92), you have to register the formats that you want to use first:

- > Decoding any particular image format requires the prior registration
  >   of a decoder function. Registration is typically automatic as a side
  >   effect of initializing that format’s package so that, to decode a PNG
  >   image, it suffices to have
- > import _ “image/png”
- > in a program’s main package. The _ means to import a package purely
  >   for its initialization side effects.

implementation example: https://play.golang.org/p/7d1gS7_tdc0

```
import (
    "image"
    // Package image/jpeg is not used explicitly in the code below,
    // but is imported for its initialization side-effect, which allows
    // image.Decode to understand JPEG formatted images. 
    _ "image/jpeg"
    "io"
)

func ImgCheckSize(file io.Reader) (io.Reader, error) {
    config, format, err := image.DecodeConfig(file)
...
```